Dirac Delta Function Integral Over Finite Interval
I am taking a course on Partial Differential Equations at the moment. We were introduced to the Dirac Delta function, and were told it satisfies
$$\int^b_a \delta(x)=1$$ for $a<0<b$.
Having taken a course on real analysis, I understand how this is true for the entire real number line, but struggle to see why this would be the case over a finite interval?
Would someone be able to explain this to me. (Thank you in advance).

All symbolic, nothing more.

You can define $$\delta_n(x)=\left{\begin{array}{cc} n/2 & \mbox{if $x \in [-1/n, 1/n]$} \ 0 & \mbox{else} \end{array}\right.$$ so that $\int_a^b \delta_n(x)dx = 1$ whenever $[-1/n,1/n]\subseteq [a,b]$. Then view $\delta$ as a "limiting form" of this as $n\rightarrow\infty$. If you want to define $\delta_n(x)$ differently so it is differentiable you can do that too, for example the Gaussian PDF with $\sigma^2=1/n$.  Of course, $\delta$ is not a real function.

Many functions satisfy $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)dx = 1$ on the entire real line but only the Dirac delta function satisfies this condition for any $a<0<b$. It is a definition

$\delta$ is the measure $\delta(A) = I(0 \in A)$. So for any set $A$ that contains $0$, $\int_{A}\delta(dx) = 1$.
